# How to prevent clustered index scan?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sapb1

I am operating in an SAP B1 database, so modifying the structure of the database is not allowed.

I have a table with 4 columns.

```
Table name: HLD1
Column  Name     Type
1       HldCode  nvarchar
2       StrDate  datetime
3       EndDate  datetime
4       Rmrks    nvarchar
```

Some of the data looks like this:

```
HldCode         StrDate                  EndDate                    Rmrks
2016 Holidays   2016-09-05 00:00:00.000  2016-09-05 00:00:00.000    Labor Day
2016 Holidays   2016-11-24 00:00:00.000  2016-11-25 00:00:00.000    Thankgiving
2016 Holidays   2016-12-26 00:00:00.000  2016-12-26 00:00:00.000    Christmas
2017 Holidays   2017-01-02 00:00:00.000  2017-01-02 00:00:00.000    New Years Day
2017 Holidays   2017-05-29 00:00:00.000  2017-05-29 00:00:00.000    Memorial Day
2017 Holidays   2017-07-04 00:00:00.000  2017-07-04 00:00:00.000    Indepenance Day
```

Notice that there is no primary key in this table.

I have a function that I have created to find the number of days between two dates, excluding holidays (as provided by the HLD1 table above) and weekends. While the function works as expected, it also takes ~.75 seconds per row that it's used in, and we're attempting to return 50000 rows to later summarize in Crystal Reports.

The piece of the function that is referencing the HLD1 table (and is causing the Clustered Index in the execution plan) looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[dateDiffHolidays] (
declare @START DATE
declare @END DATE
)

RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

SELECT @AddDays =
      (select sum(datediff(dd,strdate,enddate) + 1) from hld1
        where strdate between @START and @END) 
    + 
      (SELECT
        (DATEDIFF(wk, @Start, @End) * 2)
        +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @Start) = 'Sunday'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @End)   = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))

RETURN @AddDays

END 
GO
```

Specifically, the first part. `@START` and `@END` are the parameters passed to the function.

When I check the execution plan for the function, everything looks speedy quick, except for this piece. It gives me the following info:

[image: Clustered Index Scan]

All of the sources that I've found on the web about how to prevent or fix this kind of slowdown suggest adding indices, not referencing certain columns, etc, but since I can't modify the database, I've been unable to find any methodology on how to help in my situation.

Any suggestions?

EDIT 1:

Added Table Schema info from SQL Management

[image: Table Schema]

EDIT 2:

Added full text of function, just in case:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[dateDiffHolidays] (
@startdaytime DATETIME,
@enddaytime DATETIME
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @answer INT, @START Date, @END Date, @AddDays int

SET @answer = 0



-- Strip Times
SELECT @START = dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,@StartDayTime)), @END = 
dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,@EndDayTime))
SELECT @AddDays = (select sum(datediff(dd,strdate,enddatE) + 1) from hld1
    where strdate between @START and @END
    order by HldCode, StrDate, EndDate) + (
SELECT
  (DATEDIFF(wk, @Start, @End) * 2)
   +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @Start) = 'Sunday'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @End)   = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))

-- handle end conditions
DECLARE @firstWeekDayInRange datetime, @lastWeekDayInRange datetime;
SELECT @firstWeekDayInRange = @START, @lastWeekDayInRange = @END


WHILE @firstWeekDayInRange in (select cast( DATEADD(day, t.N - 1, StrDate) 
as date) as ResultDate 
from HLD1 s join cteTally t on t.N <= DATEDIFF(day, StrDate, EndDate) + 1)
or datepart(dw,@firstWeekDayInRange) in (1,7) 

BEGIN

SELECT @firstWeekDayInRange =
CASE
WHEN @firstWeekDayInRange in (select cast( DATEADD(day, t.N - 1, StrDate) as 
date) from HLD1 s join cteTally t on t.N <= DATEDIFF(day, StrDate, EndDate) 
+ 1)
or datepart(dw,@firstWeekDayInRange) in (1,7) 
THEN dateadd(DAY,1,@firstWeekDayInRange)
ELSE @firstWeekDayInRange
END

END 



WHILE @lastWeekDayInRange in (select cast( DATEADD(day, t.N - 1, StrDate) as 
date) as ResultDate 
from HLD1 s join cteTally t on t.N <= DATEDIFF(day, StrDate, EndDate) + 1)
or datepart(dw,@lastWeekDayInRange) in (1,7) 

BEGIN

SELECT @lastWeekDayInRange =
CASE
WHEN @lastWeekDayInRange in (select cast( DATEADD(day, t.N - 1, StrDate) as 
date) from HLD1 s join cteTally t on t.N <= DATEDIFF(day, StrDate, EndDate) 
+ 1)
or datepart(dw,@lastWeekDayInRange) in (1,7) 
THEN dateadd(DAY,-1,@lastWeekDayInRange)
ELSE @lastWeekDayInRange
END
END 


-- add one day to answer (to count Friday) if enddate was on a weekend

SELECT @answer = @answer +
CASE
-- triggered if start and end date are on same weekend
WHEN dateDiff(DAY,@firstWeekDayInRange,@lastWeekDayInRange) < 0 THEN 
 (@answer * -1)
-- otherwise count the days and substract 2 days per weekend in between dates
ELSE (DateDiff(DAY, @firstWeekDayInRange, @lastWeekDayInRange) - @AddDays)
END


RETURN @answer
END 




GO
```

Comment: How many rows are actually in the HLD1 table? Assuming that this is the actual problem step, then you should consider adding in the range of codes covering your date range. Try this variation of your code: `select sum(datediff(dd,strdate,enddate) + 1) from hld1 where strdate between @START and @END AND hldCode between CAST(Datepart(year, @START) as varchar(4)) + ' Holidays' AND CAST(Datepart(year, @END) as varchar(4)) + ' Holidays'`

Comment: That's more or less the same answer as the one provided by @Xint0 below. It doesn't speed up the function, but it does change the Clustered Index Scan to a Clustered Index Seek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by add an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
 CREATE TABLE HLD1
 (
     HldCode nvarchar(20),
     StrDate datetime,
     EndDate datetime,
     Rmrks nvarchar(50)
 )

 create unique index id_hld1 on HLD1 (HldCode, StrDate, EndDate);
 GO

INSERT INTO HLD1 
VALUES ('2016 Holidays', '2016-09-05 00:00:00.000', '2016-09-05 00:00:00.000', 'Labor Day'),
       ('2016 Holidays', '2016-11-24 00:00:00.000', '2016-11-25 00:00:00.000', 'Thanksgiving'),
       ('2016 Holidays', '2016-12-26 00:00:00.000', '2016-12-26 00:00:00.000', 'Christmas'),
       ('2017 Holidays', '2017-01-02 00:00:00.000', '2017-01-02 00:00:00.000', 'New Years Day'),
       ('2017 Holidays', '2017-05-29 00:00:00.000', '2017-05-29 00:00:00.000', 'Memorial Day'),
        ('2017 Holidays',  '2017-07-04 00:00:00.000', '2017-07-04 00:00:00.000',  'Independence Day');
GO
6 rows affected

DECLARE @StrDate datetime = '2017-01-01';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2018-01-01'

set statistics profile on;

SELECT HldCode, StrDate, EndDate, Rmrks
FROM HLD1
WHERE StrDate >= @StrDate
  AND EndDate < @EndDate;

set statistics profile off;
GO
```

Output:

```
HldCode       | StrDate             | EndDate             | Rmrks          
:------------ | :------------------ | :------------------ | :--------------
2017 Holidays | 02/01/2017 00:00:00 | 02/01/2017 00:00:00 | New Years Day  
2017 Holidays | 29/05/2017 00:00:00 | 29/05/2017 00:00:00 | Memorial Day   
2017 Holidays | 04/07/2017 00:00:00 | 04/07/2017 00:00:00 | Indepenance Day


Rows | Executes | StmtText                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | StmtId | NodeId | Parent | PhysicalOp | LogicalOp  | Argument                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | DefinedValues                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | EstimateRows | EstimateIO | EstimateCPU | AvgRowSize | TotalSubtreeCost | OutputList                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | Warnings | Type     | Parallel | EstimateExecutions
> :--- | :------- | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | -----: | -----: | -----: | :--------- | :--------- | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :----------- | :--------- | :---------- | ---------: | :--------------- | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :-----------------
> 3    | 1        | SELECT HldCode, StrDate, EndDate, Rmrks&lt;br&gt;from   HLD1&lt;br&gt;WHERE  StrDate &gt;= @StrDate&lt;br&gt;AND    EndDate &lt; @EndDate                                                                                                                                      |      1 |      1 |      0 | <em>null</em>       | <em>null</em>       | <em>null</em>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | <em>null</em>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | 1            | <em>null</em>       | <em>null</em>        |       <em>null</em> | 0.0032886        | <em>null</em>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | <em>null</em>     | SELECT   | False    | <em>null</em>              
> 3    | 1        |   |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1]), WHERE:([fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate]&gt;=[@StrDate] AND [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[EndDate]&lt;[@EndDate])) |      1 |      2 |      1 | Table Scan | Table Scan | OBJECT:([fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1]), WHERE:([fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate]&gt;=[@StrDate] AND [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[EndDate]&lt;[@EndDate]) | [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[HldCode], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[EndDate], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[Rmrks] | 1            | 0.003125   | 0.0001636   |         99 | 0.0032886        | [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[HldCode], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[EndDate], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[Rmrks] | <em>null</em>     | PLAN_ROW | False    | 1                 


DECLARE @StrDate datetime = '2017-01-01';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2018-01-01'

set statistics profile on;

SELECT HldCode, StrDate, EndDate, Rmrks
FROM HLD1
WHERE StrDate >= @StrDate
  AND EndDate < @EndDate
ORDER BY HldCode, StrDate, EndDate;

set statistics profile off;
GO
```

Output:

```
HldCode       | StrDate             | EndDate             | Rmrks          
:------------ | :------------------ | :------------------ | :--------------
2017 Holidays | 02/01/2017 00:00:00 | 02/01/2017 00:00:00 | New Years Day  
2017 Holidays | 29/05/2017 00:00:00 | 29/05/2017 00:00:00 | Memorial Day   
2017 Holidays | 04/07/2017 00:00:00 | 04/07/2017 00:00:00 | Indepenance Day

Rows | Executes | StmtText                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | StmtId | NodeId | Parent | PhysicalOp   | LogicalOp  | Argument                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         | DefinedValues                                                                                                                                                                                                   | EstimateRows | EstimateIO | EstimateCPU | AvgRowSize | TotalSubtreeCost | OutputList                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | Warnings | Type     | Parallel | EstimateExecutions
 :--- | :------- | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | -----: | -----: | -----: | :----------- | :--------- | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :----------- | :--------- | :---------- | ---------: | :--------------- | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :-----------------
 3    | 1        | SELECT HldCode, StrDate, EndDate, Rmrks&lt;br&gt;from   HLD1&lt;br&gt;WHERE  StrDate &gt;= @StrDate&lt;br&gt;AND    EndDate &lt; @EndDate&lt;br&gt;ORDER BY HldCode, StrDate, EndDate                                                                                                                                |      1 |      1 |      0 | <em>null</em>         | <em>null</em>       | <em>null</em>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | <em>null</em>                                                                                                                                                                                                            | 1            | <em>null</em>       | <em>null</em>        |       <em>null</em> | 0.00658116       | <em>null</em>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | <em>null</em>     | SELECT   | False    | <em>null</em>              
 3    | 1        |   |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Bmk1000]))                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |      1 |      2 |      1 | Nested Loops | Inner Join | OUTER REFERENCES:([Bmk1000])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | <em>null</em>                                                                                                                                                                                                            | 1            | 0          | 4.18E-06    |         99 | 0.00658116       | [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[HldCode], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[EndDate], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[Rmrks] | <em>null</em>     | PLAN_ROW | False    | 1                 
 3    | 1        |        |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[id_hld1]),  WHERE:([fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate]&gt;=[@StrDate] AND [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[EndDate]&lt;[@EndDate]) ORDERED FORWARD) |      1 |      3 |      2 | Index Scan   | Index Scan | OBJECT:([fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[id_hld1]),  WHERE:([fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate]&gt;=[@StrDate] AND [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[EndDate]&lt;[@EndDate]) ORDERED FORWARD | [Bmk1000], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[HldCode], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[EndDate] | 1            | 0.003125   | 0.0001636   |         55 | 0.0032886        | [Bmk1000], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[HldCode], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate], [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[EndDate]                                                      | <em>null</em>     | PLAN_ROW | False    | 1                 
 3    | 3        |        |--RID Lookup(OBJECT:([fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1]), SEEK:([Bmk1000]=[Bmk1000]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)                                                                                                                                               |      1 |      5 |      2 | RID Lookup   | RID Lookup | OBJECT:([fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1]), SEEK:([Bmk1000]=[Bmk1000]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD                                                                                                                                               | [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[Rmrks]                                                                                                                                                  | 1            | 0.003125   | 0.0001581   |         61 | 0.0032831        | [fiddle_9f66021924d842d39e112d909afc0794].[dbo].[HLD1].[Rmrks]                                                                                                                                                                                                       | <em>null</em>     | PLAN_ROW | False    | 1
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f67e4db957a432577d90a5a7d5bbb87c)*

**UPDATE**

As far as you need a stored procedure, you can try;

```
WITH (INDEX(IndexName))
```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[dateDiffHolidays] (@START DATE, @END DATE)
> RETURNS INT
> AS
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE @AddDays int;
>
>     SELECT @AddDays = (SELECT   sum(datediff(dd, StrDate, EndDate) + 1) 
>                        FROM     hld1 WITH (INDEX(HLD1_PRIMARY))
>                        WHERE    StrDate BETWEEN @START AND @END) 
>                        + 
>                        (SELECT (DATEDIFF(wk, @Start, @End) * 2)
>                                + (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @Start) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
>                                + (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @End) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
>
>     RETURN @AddDays
> END
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @StrDate datetime = '2017-01-01';
> DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2018-01-01';
> DECLARE @NumDays int = 0;
>
> set statistics profile on;
> EXEC @NumDays = [dbo].[dateDiffHolidays] @StrDate, @EndDate;
> set statistics profile off;
>
> SELECT @NumDays;
> ```
>
> ```
> Rows | Executes | StmtText                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | StmtId | NodeId | Parent | PhysicalOp       | LogicalOp      | Argument                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | DefinedValues                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | EstimateRows | EstimateIO | EstimateCPU | AvgRowSize | TotalSubtreeCost | OutputList                                                                                                                         | Warnings | Type     | Parallel | EstimateExecutions
> :--- | :------- | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | -----: | -----: | -----: | :--------------- | :------------- | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :----------- | :--------- | :---------- | ---------: | :--------------- | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :-----------------
> 1    | 1        | SELECT @AddDays = (SELECT   sum(datediff(dd, StrDate, EndDate) + 1) <br>                       FROM     hld1 WITH (INDEX(HLD1_PRIMARY))<br>                       WHERE    StrDate BETWEEN @START AND @END) <br>                       + <br>                       (SELECT (DATEDIFF(wk, @Start, @End) * 2)<br>                               + (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @Start) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)<br>                               + (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @End) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) |      1 |      1 |      0 | null             | null           | null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | 1            | null       | null        |       null | 0.00329658       | null                                                                                                                               | null     | SELECT   | False    | null              
> 0    | 0        |   |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1006]=[Expr1003]+(datediff(week,CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetimeoffset(7),[@START],0),CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetimeoffset(7),[@END],0))*(2)+CASE WHEN datename(weekday,[@START])=N'Sunday' THEN (1) ELSE (0) END+CASE WHEN datename(weekday,[@END])=N'Saturday' THEN (1) ELSE (0) END)))                                                                                                                                                                                                    |      1 |      2 |      1 | Compute Scalar   | Compute Scalar | DEFINE:([Expr1006]=[Expr1003]+(datediff(week,CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetimeoffset(7),[@START],0),CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetimeoffset(7),[@END],0))*(2)+CASE WHEN datename(weekday,[@START])=N'Sunday' THEN (1) ELSE (0) END+CASE WHEN datename(weekday,[@END])=N'Saturday' THEN (1) ELSE (0) END)) | [Expr1006]=[Expr1003]+(datediff(week,CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetimeoffset(7),[@START],0),CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetimeoffset(7),[@END],0))*(2)+CASE WHEN datename(weekday,[@START])=N'Sunday' THEN (1) ELSE (0) END+CASE WHEN datename(weekday,[@END])=N'Saturday' THEN (1) ELSE (0) END) | 1            | 0          | 1E-07       |         11 | 0.00329658       | [Expr1006]                                                                                                                         | null     | PLAN_ROW | False    | 1                 
> 0    | 0        |        |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1003]=CASE WHEN [Expr1012]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1013] END))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |      1 |      3 |      2 | Compute Scalar   | Compute Scalar | DEFINE:([Expr1003]=CASE WHEN [Expr1012]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1013] END)                                                                                                                                                                                                                | [Expr1003]=CASE WHEN [Expr1012]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1013] END                                                                                                                                                                                                                | 1            | 0          | 0           |         11 | 0.00329648       | [Expr1003]                                                                                                                         | null     | PLAN_ROW | False    | 1                 
> 1    | 1        |             |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1012]=COUNT_BIG([Expr1007]), [Expr1013]=SUM([Expr1007])))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |      1 |      4 |      3 | Stream Aggregate | Aggregate      | null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | [Expr1012]=COUNT_BIG([Expr1007]), [Expr1013]=SUM([Expr1007])                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | 1            | 0          | 2.3E-06     |         11 | 0.00329648       | [Expr1012], [Expr1013]                                                                                                             | null     | PLAN_ROW | False    | 1                 
> 0    | 0        |                  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1007]=datediff(day,[fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate],[fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[EndDate])+(1)))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |      1 |      5 |      4 | Compute Scalar   | Compute Scalar | DEFINE:([Expr1007]=datediff(day,[fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate],[fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[EndDate])+(1))                                                                                                                   | [Expr1007]=datediff(day,[fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate],[fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[EndDate])+(1)                                                                                                                   | 3            | 0          | 3E-07       |         11 | 0.00329418       | [Expr1007]                                                                                                                         | null     | PLAN_ROW | False    | 1                 
> 3    | 1        |                       |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[HLD1_PRIMARY]),  WHERE:([fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate]>=[@START] AND [fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate]<=[@END]))                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |      1 |      6 |      5 | Index Scan       | Index Scan     | OBJECT:([fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[HLD1_PRIMARY]),  WHERE:([fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate]>=[@START] AND [fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate]<=[@END]), FORCEDINDEX                             | [fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate], [fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[EndDate]                                                                                                                                               | 3            | 0.003125   | 0.0001636   |         23 | 0.0032886        | [fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[StrDate], [fiddle_c7abc2eb9b3f49599be6803069c6aa56].[dbo].[HLD1].[EndDate] | null     | PLAN_ROW | False    | 1                 
>
> | (No column name) |
> | ---------------: |
> |              108 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0a781e503548e4c85a00eb1b900bb3cd)*

Comment: You can't add an "order by" in a scalar-valued function, unfortunately, so this solution won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `HLD1_PRIMARY` index includes the following columns: `HldCode, StrDate, EndDate` try adding a condition that filters by `HldCode` to your aggregate select.

For example if you only want to include rows with `HldCode = '2016 Holidays'` and `HldCode = '2017 Holidays'`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[dateDiffHolidays] (
    declare @START DATE
    declare @END DATE
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @AddDays = (
        select
            sum(datediff(dd,strdate,enddate) + 1)
        from
            hld1
        where
            HldCode in ('2016 Holidays', '2017 Holidays')
            and strdate between @START and @END
    ) 
    + 
    (
        SELECT
            (DATEDIFF(wk, @Start, @End) * 2)
            +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @Start) = 'Sunday'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @End)   = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    )
    RETURN @AddDays
END
```

**UPDATE**

You won't get any better than an Index Seek for that particular query.

Then, after looking at the full code, I suspect the issue is not on that query but on the while loops used to calculate `@firstWeekDayInRange` and `@lastWeekDayInRange`:

```
WHILE @firstWeekDayInRange in (
    select
        cast(DATEADD(day, t.N - 1, StrDate) as date) as ResultDate 
    from
        HLD1 s
        join cteTally t
            on t.N <= DATEDIFF(day, StrDate, EndDate) + 1
    )
    or datepart(dw, @firstWeekDayInRange) in (1,7) 
BEGIN
    SELECT @firstWeekDayInRange =
        CASE
        WHEN @firstWeekDayInRange in (
            select
                cast(DATEADD(day, t.N - 1, StrDate) as date)
            from
                HLD1 s
                join cteTally t on
                    t.N <= DATEDIFF(day, StrDate, EndDate) + 1
        )
        or datepart(dw,@firstWeekDayInRange) in (1,7) THEN
            dateadd(DAY,1,@firstWeekDayInRange)
        ELSE
            @firstWeekDayInRange
        END
END
```

At best these queries result in the Clustered Index Scan and at worst on a Table Scan on the HLD1 table for *each* iteration of the loop, and we don't know much about cteTally, so it could be worse.

Comment: Now instead of a clustered index scan, it's causing a Clustered Index Seek, which unfortunately, isn't any faster running, it looks like.

Comment: @phroureo Try changing the HldCode line of the above query edits to: `HldCode LIKE '%Holidays'` This will result in an index scan, and also account for future years without having to worry about hard coding the year value.

Comment: Looks to be even slower with the index scan... I ran "SELECT top 10" and it took 23 seconds.

Comment: The execution plan tells me that the issue lies with the line I stated above. In addition, in a previous version of the function (that didn't take holidays into account), it did not have the slowness issues that it's having now, so I would say the slowness is attributable to the HLD1 table query.

What would you suggest as far as expediting the query goes? Should I create another table with the holiday values in it as well as a primary key, and query from there? Would that speed it up?

Comment: From the screenshots you have provided, the HLD1 table has a primary key index that includes HldCode, StrDate, EndDate, and it is being used.  You can try copying the HLD1 table and creating an index that includes only StrDate and EndDate.

Answer (score 0):

Do you must use a function? how about create a date calendar kind of table?

```
CREATE TABLE #Datecalendar
(DateId DATE PRIMARY KEY
, IsWeekend BIT DEFAULT 0
, IsHoliday BIT DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE #HLD1
(HldCode nvarchar(20)
, StrDate datetime
, EndDate datetime
, Rmrks nvarchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO #HLD1 
VALUES ('2016 Holidays', '2016-09-05 00:00:00.000', '2016-09-05 00:00:00.000', 'Labor Day'),
   ('2016 Holidays', '2016-11-24 00:00:00.000', '2016-11-25 00:00:00.000', 'Thanksgiving'),
   ('2016 Holidays', '2016-12-26 00:00:00.000', '2016-12-26 00:00:00.000', 'Christmas'),
   ('2017 Holidays', '2017-01-02 00:00:00.000', '2017-01-02 00:00:00.000', 'New Years Day'),
   ('2017 Holidays', '2017-05-29 00:00:00.000', '2017-05-29 00:00:00.000', 'Memorial Day'),
    ('2017 Holidays',  '2017-07-04 00:00:00.000', '2017-07-04 00:00:00.000',  'Independence Day');


WITH cte AS (SELECT CAST('2016-01-01' AS DATE) AS DateId
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT   DATEADD(dd, 1, DateId)
                      FROM cte
                      WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, DateId) <= '2019-01-01'
)
INSERT INTO #Datecalendar 
(DateId
, IsWeekend
, IsHoliday
)
SELECT DateId
,CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,DateId) =1 OR DATEPART(WEEKDAY,DateId) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  
,CASE WHEN h.HldCode IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM cte cte
LEFT JOIN #HLD1 h
ON cte.DateId BETWEEN h.StrDate AND h.EndDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #Datecalendar
WHERE DateId BETWEEN '2016-05-06' AND '2017-02-24'
AND IsWeekend = 0 
AND IsHoliday = 0;

DROP TABLE #HLD1;
DROP TABLE #Datecalendar;
```